# How to post data to WCF Service using jquery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, wcf-security

I am facing issue in consuming WCF service using JQUERY AJAX. I know this is cross domain issue and have read alot of solution about it. but none worked for me. Below is all the related code. Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [return: MessageParameter(Name = "result")]


        public ServiceSearchResponse GetSearchResults(ServiceSearchParams sParams)
        {
            /// search function
        }
```

JQUERY:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://myserviceurl.com/GetSearchResults",
            data: p,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {

                alert(data);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('failed');
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        });
```

Webconfig:

```
  <system.webServer>        
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
      </system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
          <!--Added DefaultServiceBehavior referenced at service tag above-->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>       
        <behavior name="myserives.services.AppServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior">

          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>  
      <service name="mypackage.services.MyServices">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="myserives.services.AppServicesAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="LargeSizeMessages" contract="myContractName"  />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeSizeMessages" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">      
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is how it looks like:
http://screencast.com/t/b7tsqld6

See error :
http://screencast.com/t/pWQNAlmMYS3

And nothing in post data. though i m posting data.

--- UPDATE

See my Global.asax .. i am doing something wrong here:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall();
        }

        private void EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                          "*");

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                              "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
                             "true");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                              "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age",
                              "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you getting ? Can u explain your issue which you are facing ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a piece of working code.

**Interface**

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IDataService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)]
        List<RequestData> GetUser(RequestData data);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "UsersList/{id}",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)]
        RequestData UsersList(string id);



    }
```

**Class implementing interface**

```
public class DataService : IDataService
    {

        public List<RequestData> GetUser(RequestData data)
        {
            List<RequestData> list = new List<RequestData>();
            if (data.Name.ToUpper() == "MAIRAJ")
            {
                list.Add(new RequestData
                {
                    Name = "Mairaj",
                    Age = 25,
                    Address = "Test Address"
                });
                list.Add(new RequestData
                {
                    Name = "Ahmad",
                    Age = 25,
                    Address = "Test Address"
                });

            }
            return list;
        }
        public RequestData UsersList(string userId)
        {
                return new RequestData
                {
                    Name = "Mairaj",
                    Age = 25,
                    Address = "Test Address"
                };
         }

    }
```

**Custom Class**

As i am passing object of this class as parameter to method and returning object of this so i am using this. You may not need it.

```
[DataContract]
    public class RequestData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Address { get; set; }

    }
```

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WCFWebApp.DataService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFWebApp.IDataService" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here is how you call it

```
var Data = {
        Name: "Mairaj",
        Age: 20,
        Address: "Test Address"
        //userId:1
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DataService.svc/GetUser",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: JSON.stringify(Data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Data is " + data);
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
```

You need to change name of service classes in web.config and url in jquery code from where you will call it.

Comment: Thanks alot Mairaj Ahmad. But the problem is this is not cross domain call. Try to use this service cross domain and see if it is working for you.

Comment: In your screenshot it looks like Access-Control-Allow-Origin has the value. *,*. Should only be:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Comment: Try this , it should work cross domain as well. @IrfanTahirKheli

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true** i web.config.
Also try setting the **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** to the header that match your jquery ajax call. Should be "application/json", but check with fiddler (or similar) to be sure.
Finally try setting the **Access-Control-Request-Method: POST**

I hade similar problems and after experimenting with different settings i web.config I managed to find a combination that actually worked. Good luck :)

**UPDATE**

Also, I would make sure that the access-control-allow-credentials is in the same case- form as the other parameters. I.e. Access-control-allow-credentials. I don't really have any source on this, but just in case :)

I would try this without using localhost. Setup your test environments on different servers with proper host names.At least Chrome has had problems handling cors on localhost.

According to http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ the Content-type of the request should be one of the following:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

**UPDATE 2**

More things you could try: 
Add:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

before the

```
$.ajax({ ...
```

I think that the problems could be cased by incorrect content type. 
When I did a CORS setup to a Sharepoint 2013 server I added this and it all worked:

```
headers: { 
  "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8",
  "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8"
},
```

That content-type might not be relevant for you, but I might be important to specify like that.

Comment: Thanks Paul.. I have have checked these settings. still unable to get it working. :( .. see the links show request and response headers. and error message.

Comment: see my global.asax code updated in question.. See if i am doing something wrong there.

Comment: Added another update. Your code loks fine. Analyze the actual Ajax calls to make sure you have the corrent content-type.

Comment: still no luck paul. :(

Comment: That sux! The whole CORS-implementation is very "sensitive". Specially since the browsers have slightly different implementations and servers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add requested domain in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` instead of `*`, `*` might not work in all browsers , as it a security issue - i.e. only requested domain should be allowed in `OPTIONS` request, not * should be responded in options response header. To solve this, you need to change that code to following.

`HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");`

Replace `http://localhost` with requested domain name, to do it programatically you can use this - `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"].ToString()`.

I have explained this in my blog in more detail- [Blog](https://arindamnayak1.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/enabling-cors-in-wcf/), [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/845474/Enabling-CORS-in-WCF)

Comment: Thanks Arindam Nayak. I have downloaded your code. and used it exactly. http://screencast.com/t/V75heErUbM9 this is what i am getting.

Comment: First, you need to update code to use correct request host i.e. change value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `http://localhost:59427` , then make sure you can access `.svc` directly in browser, I mean just check if you have correct IIS setting.

Comment: yeh iis setting is fine. More i can't fix the origin because i also have to consume same apis to develop apps using Phonegap. How can i do that then?

Comment: Yes, I am saying to fix for experimental purpose, just to see if CORS issue is solved, anyway you can use the suggestion I mentioned in answer , i..e use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"].ToString()` . Can you try setting content type in original JS call and set also here in begin request.